# How to roll over log files in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, log

**Roll over** log fies in Magento 2,
 because after some extend **debug.log, system.log and exception.log** files size is exceeding, so i want to roll over the file after some extend (**10 Mb**).

Comment: You can simply delete it and magento will create a new one for you.

Comment: I know, It will create new file when i manually deleted log file, but my question is how to roll over log file after some extend ? @userpk